# RmiProxyFactoryBean afterPropertiesSet() throwing exception

Tags: java, spring, rmi

I have a question about this method & I was hoping someone here could help.

I have looked up the API & various posts about this but there is still something I am not sure of.
[RmiProxyFactoryBean API](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/remoting/rmi/RmiProxyFactoryBean.html#afterPropertiesSet())

When this method throws an exception due to a misconfiguration, is it a misconfiguration of the RmiProxyFactoryBean object that I have created, or a misconfiguration of the service I am trying to connect to?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Could be either. Could be a problem in your infrastructure (firewall port that is closed for instance), trying to connect to a different JDK version might be a problem... So it can be a whole lot of issues there isn't a single point to point to.

Comment: Too general question. There won't be a correct answer without providing specific exception & stacktrace.